# HTML table row becomes editable text box

Tags: html, html-table

Building a full stack app which loads a list of songs from an api into a table. How can I make a row's fields editable when the user clicks on the Edit button?

Maybe using a modal would be better?

The API is running on Rails and the table is generated using a template engine Handlebars.

[image: Songs table]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable

Comment: More than one awnser possible. But the most common would be an on click event where you switch content and place it into an input. Or you make them already input, but uneditable, and remove that when click on edit. What have you tried so far

Comment: Unfortunately there's no built-in "make this editable and save back to my database" function.  What you'll need to do is break apart the overall goal into small individual pieces and write code to achieve each of those.  There are a variety of approaches you can take, a variety of tools you can use, etc.  As it stands this question is far too broad to be meaningfully answered here.  Start with any piece of the overall puzzle and make some attempt.  When you do this, if you get stuck on a specific technical problem then we can help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using JavaScript and uniqueIDs generated most likely from the database.

In the below example, wherever the number "10" is used it is meant to renote the presence of a uniqueID, NOT just as a string 10. AKA, in a working example, is ten would be a uniqueID you have generated from a database, and linked to the code below.

The example:

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>Song Name</th>
<th>Artist</th>
<th>Genre</th>
<th colspan="2">Actions</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
//Whatever code here should be written in something like PHP which can 
return multiple values of the example I've written.
<tr id="tr_10">
<td id="songName_10">Nightcall</td>
<td id="songArtist_10">Kavinsky</td>
<td id="songGenre_10">Synthwave</td>
<td><button onclick="editSongInfo(10)">Edit</button></td>
<td><button>Remove</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<script>
function editSongInfo(uniqueId){
var x = document.getElementById("songName_" + uniqueId);
x.innerHTML = "<input type='text' placeholder='Enter edited song name 
here.'>";
x = document.getElementById("songArtist_" + uniqueId);
x.innerHTML = "<input type='text' placeholder='Enter edited song artist 
here.'>";
x = document.getElementById("songGenre_" + uniqueId);
x.innerHTML = "<input type='text' placeholder='Enter edited song genre 
here.'>";
}
</script>
```

This will change your text to an input upon click, but it will not submit the response to the database, as that is not  the question you asked, and you have not provided any code, or frameworks you wish to use, or even how you access you database.

This answer is the best I can provide with the information you have supplied, which is an image of a table and the tags, "html" and "html-table"

Working example of the above code, here: http://jsfiddle.net/fo2z1vLa/11/